# Transaction script implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, transactions, dto

Could you please advice me which of these two (if any) approaches to Transaction Script patter is correct?

Basically I need to implement "pure" TS, which is not to bend it in some convenient way. And the question is when I get data from Table Data Gateway shall I store them, for different parts (logical part for sake of clarity) of transaction and use them where do I need, OR get data don't store them but directly use them and if the same data are needed again call table gateway and ask for it.

Example: http://pastebin.com/hGCgrfEs

Thanks. Hopefully it makes sense if not let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The TSDoSomething2 class is closer to a good solution, i propose this to implement a SOLID transcript implementation:

```
public class OrderBusiness : IAcceptVisitOrder
{
    private readonly string _id;

    private int _status;

    public OrderBusiness(string id, int status)
    {
        _id = id;
        _status = status;
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(int newStatus)
    {
        //validation logic....
        _status = newStatus;
    }

    public void Accept(IOrderVisitor visitor)
    {
        if (visitor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(visitor));
        visitor.Visit(_id, _status);
    }
}

public class Client
{
    private readonly OrderApplicationService _service;
    //Get from Service locator like ninject, etc
    private readonly IReader<OrderBusiness, string> _reader = new OrderBusinessReader();
    private readonly IOrderVisitor _visitor = new UpdateOrderVisitor();

    public Client()
    {
        _service = new OrderApplicationService(_reader, _visitor);
    }
    public void Run(UpdateOrderCommand command)
    {
        _service.When(command);
    }
}

public class UpdateOrderCommand
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

public class OrderApplicationService
{
    private readonly IReader<OrderBusiness, string> _reader;
    private readonly IOrderVisitor _visitor;

    public OrderApplicationService(IReader<OrderBusiness, string> reader, IOrderVisitor visitor)
    {
        if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
        if (visitor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(visitor));
        _reader = reader;
        _visitor = visitor;
    }

    public void When(UpdateOrderCommand command)
    {
        var order = GetBusinessObject(command.Id);
        order.ChangeStatus(command.Status);
        order.Accept(_visitor);
    }

    private OrderBusiness GetBusinessObject(string id)
    {
        if (id == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
        return _reader.Read(id);
    }
}

public interface IReader<out T, in TK>
{
    T Read(TK id);
}

public interface IAcceptVisitOrder
{
    void Accept(IOrderVisitor visitor);
}

public interface IOrderVisitor
{
    void Visit(string id, int status);
}

public class OrderBusinessReader : IReader<OrderBusiness, string>
{
    public OrderBusiness Read(string id)
    {
        //Read data from db with EF, ADO.NET, ETC
        var status = 0;
        return new OrderBusiness(id, status); 
    }
}

class UpdateOrderVisitor : IOrderVisitor
{
    public void Visit(string id, int status)
    {
        //Persist to database, etc
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!
Regards!